# What is wrong with docker command?

Tags: docker

I m new to docker & trying some samples. I tried python example provided on docker site. I executed the command

```
docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
```

I am getting below error

`docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint clever_pare (5625ad3f5e3d5ffdcf5d45bec60f4bac87925b37205b5adff6304712eb3eef88): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:4000:tcp:172.17.0.2:80: input/output error.`

Not able to understand what is wrong. Please provide solution for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error can happen, if the port you are using,`4000` in this case, is already in use. In other cases, this is almost always related to some iptables or firewall problem. It can also happen, if you are using a free WIFI which uses a captive portal site.

Answer (score -1):

as Kevin said, make sure port 4000 is not already in use. Additionally, run docker commands with **sudo**.

Comment: He doesn't need `sudo`. He connected to the docker daemon just fine without it. The only issue is that it failed to setup the host port proxy.